# QR method for Hessenberg matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

In trying to implement the method, my approach is to use a reduction to Hessenberg form, and then to iterate using a QR method of Givens rotations. However, I am having trouble successfully implementing the Givens rotations, since I'm only worried about the $n-1$ entries of the off-diagonal, in a manner of speaking. Included is my MATLAB code:

```
function [H,Q,R] = hessQR(A,maxIter)

[H,P] = HHhess(A);
for k = 1:maxIter
   [Q,R] = HGivQR(H);
   A = R*Q;
end
end


function [Q,R] = HGivQR(A)
n = size(A,1);
Q=eye(n);
R=A;
for j=1:n-1    
    for i=n:(-1):j+1        
        x=R(:,j);   
        if norm([x(i-1),x(i)])>0       
            c=x(i-1)/norm([x(i-1),x(i)]);
            s=-x(i)/norm([x(i-1),x(i)]);
            G=eye(n);
            G([i-1,i],[i-1,i])=[c,s;-s,c];
            R=G'*R;
            Q=Q*G;
        end
    end
end
end
```

The method converges, but my real Schur decomposition (which is R in my code) is not correct... nor is A==Q*R. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I think it might be in my Givens code. Please, point out mistakes you see that I have made!

Comment: I'd suggest you to first check the main loop and have a look what's going on with $A$ and $H$.

Comment: Also note that if $QR=H$ is a QR factorization of an upper Hessenberg matrix $H$, then $RQ$ is again an upper Hessenberg matrix. Only $n-1$ Givens rotations (compared to $O(n^2)$) is needed to QR-factorize a Hessenberg matrix.